# book-list.component.ts:52 Error occured. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'books') Project is made in angular

Tags: html, angular, spring, typescript

I tried many things but somehow I can't get it to display the books this way. My goal here is to display products with a certain category for example: `http://localhost:4200/books/category/1`
it worked without category but now when I added some code it displays the following error:

> book-list.component.ts:52 Error occured. TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'books')

Project is made in angular

This is my **Service class**, where I have the GET method(getBookList())

```
import { Book } from './../common/book';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BookService {
  private baseUrl: string = environment.apiUrl + "/book";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}


  getBookList(theCategoryId: number): Observable<Book[]>{

    const searchUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/book/category/${theCategoryId}`;

    return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(searchUrl).pipe(map(
      response => response._embedded.books
    ));
  }


interface GetResponse {
  _embedded: {
    books: Book[]
  }
}
```

This is my component.ts

```
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { Book } from './../../common/book';
import { BookService } from './../../services/book.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-list',
  templateUrl: './book-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-list.component.css']
})
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {

  books: Book[] = [];
  currentCategoryId: number = 1;

  // private baseUrl: string = `${environment.apiUrl}/book`;


  constructor(
    private bookService: BookService,
    // private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(() => {
      this.listBooks();
    });
  }

  listBooks() {

    // check if "id" parameter is available
    const hasCategoryId: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('id');
    
    if (hasCategoryId) {
      // get the "id" param string. convert string to a number using the "+" symbol
      this.currentCategoryId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    }
    else {
      // not category id available ... default to category id 1
      this.currentCategoryId = 1;
    }

    this.bookService.getBookList(this.currentCategoryId).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.books = data;
        console.log(data);
        
    }, error => {
      console.log('Error occured.', error);
      
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the HTML file

```
<!-- Product info -->
<section class="section has-background-grey-light">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="columns is-vcentered is-multiline">

            <div class="column is-3-desktop is-12-tablet is-12-mobile" *ngFor="let book of books">

                <div class="card">

                    <div class="card-image">
                        <figure class="image is-4by3">
                            <img src="{{ book?.imageUrl }}" alt="Placeholder image">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content has-text-left">
                        <div class="media">

                            <div class="media-content">
                                <p class="is-size-5-tablet is-size-5-mobile is-size-5-desktop title">{{ book?.name }}</p>
                                <p class="is-size-6-tablet is-size-8-mobile is-size-6-desktop subtitle">by {{ book?.author }}</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="card-footer-item">

                            <div class="buttons">
                                <a class="button is-info">
                                    <strong>Reserve</strong>
                                </a>
                                <a class="button is-light">
                                  Rate
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Product info end -->
```

and this is what I get in console

```
 Error occured. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'books')
    at book.service.ts:21:38
    at map.js:7:1
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:1)
    at map.js:7:1
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:1)
    at filter.js:6:50
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:1)
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory, which occurred in your BookService. Is `response._embedded.books` valid path?

Comment: That would be an interface GetResponse which I made as a response object to my method. I am a beginner in angular @Rana_S

Comment: Check the actual response structure whether the response contains _`embedded` or not by either printing the response or debugging.

Comment: @Rana_S how do I do that? for example if I used class Book[] instead of interface GetResponse I get another error "ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
"

Comment: {"content":[{"id":1,"name":"","author":"","description":"The path to you life's work is difficult and risky, even scary, which .","imageUrl":"assets/images/1/art_of_work.jpg","pages":240,"quantity":10,"dateCreated":"2022-07-29","publishedAt":2015},"pageable":{"sort":{"empty":true,"sorted":false,"unsorted":true},"offset":0,"pageNumber":0,"pageSize":20,"unpaged":false,"paged":true},"last":true,"totalPages":1,"totalElements":10,"size":20,"number":0,"sort":{"empty":true,"sorted":false,"unsorted":true},"first":true,"numberOfElements":1,"empty":false} @Rana_S  This is how it looks when I run backend

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your response I would say the reason it's throwing an error is because getBookList() method in service is trying to get data from wrong path: `response._embedded.books` .

It should be `response._embedded.content` instead of `response._embedded.books`

and interface would be:

```
interface GetResponse {
  _embedded: {
    content: Book[]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now.  The solution was:    interface GetResponse {
    content: Book[]
}

Comment: Yeah it depends on what api returns.